# Ggplot2 axis label from column name of apply function iteration

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to change the y axis label (or main title would also be fine) of a ggplot to reflect the column name being iterated over within an apply function.

Here is some sample data and my working apply function:

```
trial_df <- data.frame("Patient" = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4), 
                       "Outcome" = c("NED", "NED", "NED", "NED", "Relapse","Relapse","Relapse","Relapse"),
                       "Time_Point" = c("Baseline", "Week3", "Baseline", "Week3","Baseline", "Week3","Baseline", "Week3"),
                       "CD4_Param" = c(50.8,53.1,20.3,18.1,30.8,24.5,35.2,31.0),
                       "CD8_Param" = c(5.3,9.7,4.4,4.3,3.1,3.2,5.6,5.3),
                       "CD3_Param" = c(11.6,16.6,5.0,5.1,14.3,7.1,5.9,8.1))

apply(trial_df[,4:length(trial_df)], 2, function(i) ggplot(data = trial_df, aes_string(x = "Time_Point", y = i )) +
        facet_wrap(~Outcome) +
        geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.1) +
        geom_point(aes(color = `Outcome`, fill = `Outcome`)) +
        geom_path(aes(group = `Patient`, color = `Outcome`)) +
        theme_minimal() +
        ggpubr::stat_compare_means( method = "wilcox.test") +
        scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "red")) +
        scale_color_manual(values=c("blue", "red")))
```

[Example plot output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6Ud7.png)

This creates 3 graphs as expected, however the y axis just says "y". I would like this to display the column name for the column in that iteration. It would also be fine to add a main title with this information, as I just need to know which graph corresponds to which column.

Here are things I have already tried adding to the ggplot code above based on some similar questions I found, but all of them give me the error "non-numeric argument to binary operator":

`ggtitle(paste(i))`
`labs(y = i)`
`labs(y = as.character(i))`

Any help or resources I may have missed would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried looping through the *names* of the y variables instead of the columns of the dataset? Then you could switch to, e.g., `lapply()` with the same ggplot2 code. (Note `aes_string()` is now deprecated; you can use the `.data` pronoun a la `y = .data[[column name]]` if looping through column names and making ggplot2 plots.)

Comment: Using the colnames and apply solved the problem! Thanks so much for the suggestion @aosmith!
For anyone who stumbles upon this later, here is what I did: `lapply(colnames(trial_df[,4:length(trial_df)]),function(i) ggplot(...)`

Answer (score 0):

So.....for the strangest of reasons I cannot figure out why. This gives what you want but for only one graph!!!

```
apply(trial_df[,4:length(trial_df)], 2, function(i) ggplot(data = trial_df, aes_string(x = "Time_Point", y = i )) +
        facet_wrap(~Outcome) +
        geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.1) +
        geom_point(aes(color = `Outcome`, fill = `Outcome`)) +
        geom_path(aes(group = `Patient`, color = `Outcome`)) +
        theme_minimal() +
        stat_compare_means( method = "wilcox.test") +
        scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "red")) +
        scale_color_manual(values=c("blue", "red"))+
        labs(y=colnames(trial_df)[i]))
```

Gives these:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP is looking for; you are showing the first value of each column (e.g. 50.8), not the column name (e.g. CD4_Param).

Comment: Oooops...I'll get on that. Good eye!

Comment: I've tried a million different ways to get this, but only getting the y axis for the `CD8_Param` graph is the best I can get. Would love someone to solve this and explain why!

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me! I have absolutely no idea why that was happening there, I was getting the same issue. I still don't know what is happening here, but was able to solve my bigger/original problem by using lapply to loop through the names, as suggested by the above comment under my initial question.

Comment: Fantastic! Post an answer to yourself so that others having the same problem can solve it.